# Добавление текста со смещением

Tags: php, html, javascript

Необходимо сделать с помощью PHP смещение массива/текста. Например было так:

> Текст1
> Текст2
> Текст3

Должно стать так:

> Текст4
> Текст1
> Текст2

Каким способом это можно реализовать. Желательно без БД.

Answer (score 1):

Метки ваши запутывают.
Если нужно на php, то

```
$array = array('Текст1', 'Текст2', 'Текст3');
$new_item = array('Текст 4');

$result = array_merge($new_item, $array);

print_r($result);
```

Если на javascript, то принцип тот же:

```
var array = ['Текст1', 'Текст2', 'Текст3'];
a.unshift('Текст 4');

console.log(a);
```

Comment: @dimka3210, где тут смещение?

Comment: @XenK unshift

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял Вас, и вам необходимо, чтобы список выводился не последовательно, а вразброс, то Вам стоит попробовать функцию shuffle. Данная функция перемешивает массив.